# when sending text it directs me to use skype instead why

Tags: skype

when i try to send a text to someone new it sends me to skype. why. SayI get a call and want to send them a text it sends me to skype instead of allowing me to send a regular text message

Comment: What is your default sms application?

Answer (score 0):

Check your default SMS application. Go to `Settings > More` and tap `Default SMS app`.You can select the desired one from here.